# How to get value of the object with props in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I've got a problem with getting the value of the object with props. I mean I've got data in JSON and I use fetch to get it, but that's actually a component and I want to have different data based on props. How to properly select the property in the object?

**JSON:**

```
{
  "example1": [
    {
      "title": "title1"
    }
  ],
  "example2": [
    {
      "title": "title2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
import Child from './Child';
const Parent = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Child prop={'example1'}/>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Parent;
```

**Child component:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Child = ({prop}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const getData = async () => {
        await fetch('./data.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData(data);

            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])


    return ( 
        {`${data}.${prop}`?.map((item) => (
           <div>{item.title}</div>
        ))}
     );
}
 
export default Child;
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what's being asked, but a thought I have is if you want to access the key in the object based on the value of `prop` you could extract that from the data object before storing it in your data state. `.then(data => setData(data[prop]))`.

Comment: @user8566336 yep, that's all :P Post your comment as a solution for my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you store your data in the `data` state you can extract the data you want using the `prop` prop passed into the component. Then you can set that to the `data` state.

`.then(data => setData(data[prop]))`